# htaccess redirect specific url's to new domain

Tags: .htaccess

due to a new system we want to redirect some pages of our current website to a new domain. I found a solution to redirect the whole traffic to a new domain

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NEWDOMAIN.com [R=301,L]
```

But for example I just want some specific url's to be redirected. For example:

```
olddomain.com/user/login => newdomain.com
olddomain.com/freestuff => newdomain.com/freestuff
olddomain.com/order/course => newdomain.com/book-course
olddomain.com/order/course?course=1 => newdomain.com/book-course?course_id=1
```

For all of the urls I want also that all GET Parameters will be included (see last example).

I'm not that familiar with regular expressions and can't figure it out how to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup separate rules for each specific URL you want to redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?user/login$ https://example.com/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?freestuff $ https://example.com/freestuff  [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?order/course$ https://example.com/book-course[R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)course=(\d+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?order/course$ https://example.com/book-course?course_id=%1  [R=301]
```

In general it is better to implement such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of relying on dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"), but both is possible.